# When integrating json data from redux saga, am getting type of error landig.Slots is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, saga

landing.js:

> {landing && landing.Slots && landing.Slots.map((slot, index) => {
>                   if (slot && !slot.removed) {
>                     let fullWidth = "100%";
>                     let maxWidth = 576;
>                     let style = {};
>                     style["width"] = fullWidth;
>                     style["maxWidth"] = fullWidth;
>                     style["height"] = slot.HeightPixel + "px";
>                     return (
>                       
>                         
>                       
>                     );
>                   }
>                 })}
>             
>   Json data:

{
  "data":{
     "id":1,
     "lastUpdatedOn":1543843081000,
     "createdOn":1543843081000,
     "pageUID":"SLLXHJ1",
     "languageTag":"en-us",
     "type":"Home",
     "name":"Home",
     "description":"Home page",
     "slots":[
        {
           "id":1,
           "lastUpdatedOn":1543843246000,
           "createdOn":1543843246000,
           "slotUID":"XYSSLK1",
           "platformSupported":"iPhone,Android",
           "type":"Banner",
           "name":"Lacoste",
           "widthInPixel":375,
           "heightInPixel":60,
           "layers":[
              {
                 "id":1,
                 "layerUID":"XXSLES1",
                 "name":"",
                 "type":"Rectangle",
                 "attributes":{
                    "fillColor":"000000",
                    "contentMode":"Fill",
                    "viewAlignment":"CentreAlignedFlexibleWidth",
                    "frame":"[0,0,375,60]"
                 },
                 "index":0
              },
              {
                 "id":2,
                 "layerUID":"LFSLES2",
                 "name":"",
                 "type":"Text",
                 "attributes":{
                    "fillColor":"000000",
                    "numberOfLines":"1",
                    "multiline":"flase",
                    "textAlignment":"Left",
                    "label":"Shop a minimum of two products to twin!",
                    "textColor":"FFFFFF",
                    "value":"Shop a minimum of two products to twin!",
                    "frame":"[20,21,279,20]",
                    "viewAlignment":"LeftAligned",
                    "font":{
                       "size":"14",
                       "name":"Avenir-Heavy"
                    }
                 },

Comment: `landing !== landig`. You have a typo, friend.

Comment: still i got error

Comment: You also seem to have "Slots" and "slots". Pay attention to how you spell your properties.

Comment: i changed Slots as slots also am getting same error

Comment: What does the error say now? Can you paste it in a comment?

Comment: type of error landig.Slots is undefined